# Skip checking modules from node_modules by Webpack + TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

I use https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals module to exclude node_modules from bundling into the destination file.

I still have an issue when Webpack checks imported files from node_modules folder for validity. It leads to errors like:

> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/myuser/myproject/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:210:4 
>   Unreachable code detected.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/myuser/myproject/node_modules/json-schema/lib/validate.js:43:9 
>   Duplicate identifier 'validate'.
>
> ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/myuser/myproject/node_modules/json-schema/lib/validate.js:68:4 
>   Duplicate identifier 'validate'.

How do I make it skip checking these external modules?